# The Convert method of WkHtmlToPdfDotNet nuget does nothing, just wait

Tags: c#, pdf

I use WkHtmlToPdfDotNet nuget to generate PDFs.

For long everything was fine, but a few days, the pdf generation reaches IConverter's Convert() method and nothing happenes. No memory increase, zero CPU usage not reaching the next breakpoint.

I created a console application with the sample code but behavias the same.

https://github.com/HakanL/WkHtmlToPdf-DotNet

I don't know what to do.

Thank you!